# How to merge objects seamlessly

Tags: modifiers

I applied the `boolean` modifier in union mode to a rod, set `object` to another rod, and this way created this arrow:

[image: Arrow in edit mode with unneeded vertices and edges]

You can see, that there are unneeded vertices and edges. So how can I

1. **Automatically** delete them
2. Or merge them without creating these vertices/edges?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot showing what the two rods look like before the Boolean (showing the vertices) and another of the Boolean showing its settings.  Your screenshot suggests that there is a problem with the topology of your rods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those situations where precision matters.  Here's an example that produces similar results to yours:

[image: similar cross with extra geometry]

This is because I used the Fast Solver.  Now I switch the Solver to Exact and the problem goes away:

[image: Extra geometry gone because of using the fast solver.]

Here is the Boolean I used:

[image: Boolean with exact solver]

Be aware that this only works if the end faces of the cubes line up exactly.  To accomplish this, I used snapping in vertex mode to align the faces of each rod to the side of the other rod:

Here is one of the rods before alignment:

[image: rod not aligned]

Here is what it looks like when I move the end on the X axis and snap it into place:

[image: Aligned properly]

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that you were using 2.83.  This is a 2.9x option.

Comment: I updated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the single vertices and dissolve with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices*. You can dissolve the edge with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*. You can also use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.